# HttpPost get HTTP response code Android

Tags: android, http

I'm using

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));
```

in order to send data to my webservice. How could I get the http response code (like 200, 404, 500, etc) ?

I'm not able to use `getResponseCode()` from `HttpURLConnection`

Comment: No problem :) I'll mark it so it can be closed

Comment: I already hit 'flag this post' :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More of your code would be helpful here but the way I do it is this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

Comment: Class not resolving in Android

Answer (score 1):

by

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int code = statusline.getStatusCode();
```